# Multiple-Row Subquery Operators

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

I just finished taking an exam for an Intro to Oracle class. I failed to answer this question correctly for, what I believe to be, obvious reasons.

---

QUESTION:
Which comparison operator cannot be used with multiple-row subqueries?

A. ALL

B. ANY

C. IN

D. All of the above

---

As far as my understanding goes, all of these are comparison operators specifically used for multiple-row subqueries. Is this a faulty question, or is there something I'm missing?
[I understand that the ANY and ALL operator require a single-row operator (i.e > < = != etc) to be used in conjunction, however this is not addressed in the question.]
Just looking for some confirmation that I'm not mistaken before I email my professor.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes question is wrong. Actually last option should **None of the above**

Comment: That's what I thought. Thank you for the confirmation.

Comment: English is funny with double negation. The best way to fix the question is to keep the answers, and change "cannot" to "can" in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of them can be used with multi row sub query. Confirmation from the oracle itself 
https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/all-any-some-comparison-conditions-in-sql#any